# Memory leak after game is quit

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

i have a question about cocos2d-x memory leak in IOS.i just google this but not found a satisfied answer,so i hope i can get hep from here.
first,i am using the version 2.2.5,i know when we create a sprite via create(),its retainCount will be 1,if we added this sprite to a CCArray,its retainCount will be 2.if we want to delete it,just make sure its retainCount become 0,thus cocos2d-x engine will help us delete it from memory.my problem is in IOS,do we need to reclaim the memory manually when the game is quit or killed?

1.i do not see any callback function which is about game ends

2.suppose there is a such callback function(called when application is end),do we need to manually reclaim memory in here?e.g for my example,there is some global variables whose retainCount is 2,do we need to release it again in here?

3.if we don't care the memory leaks when game ends,does it means it is possible lead to memory leak when game ends?
any suggestion means a lot for me,thx!

Answer (score 1):

The allocated memory is all within your process space so is all recovered when your process ends. It is not possible leak memory when your app ends. You only need to worry about memory usage while your app is running.

See [interesting article here](http://www.slideshare.net/OwenGoss/finding-and-fixing-memory-leaks-in-ios-apps-5251292)